# randomly rename files in php

Tags: php, random, rename

I have a folder of 1000 images and I need to randomly rename them from 1.jpg to 1000.jpg , it must be completely random each time I run the script.
I just need that 1.jpg is different each time I run the script.

all I have to work with so far is the following code.
Please help. Thanks

```
<?php

if (file_exists('Image00001.jpg'))
{
$renamed= rename('Image00001.jpg', '1.jpg');

if ($renamed)
{
echo "The file has been renamed successfully";
}
else
{
echo "The file has not been successfully renamed";
}
}
else
{
echo "The original file that you want to rename does not exist";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to rename the files in such a manner? If you want to select a random image, grab all file names from the directory, should be in an array and just shuffle that.

Comment: because the image must be called 1.jpg

Comment: basically what I need is each time I run the script I get one of the 1000 images to be renamed 1.jpg, it could be random or incremental. thanks

Comment: What happens after the first time?  After you have a `1.jpg` you can't then rename another one to `1.jpg`...

Comment: Again. Why does it need to be renamed each and every time? 1000 renames on each request is a heavy file system operation. There are much better ways, without renaming. You just need to approach it differently. A filename is irrelevant, just store it in a variable for the one your going to use

Comment: 1.jpg could be deleted before the next file is renamed 1.jpg

Comment: the script only needs to rename one of the files to 1.jpg each time the script is run

Comment: Why do you need to rename the images randomly?  There is probably an easier way to do what you are doing if you can explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a folder on my website with 1000 images, each time I run the php script I need to have a different image called 1.jpg, the image can be taken from any of the images in the folder but it must be always renamed to 1.jpg, the 1.jpg image can be overwritten each time I run the script, I am using IFTTT to post an image and the file must always be called 1.jpg. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out, if this helps. I tried it out and it works. Create a php file and copy the code, and in the same directory create a folder name **files** and fill it with images with extension **.jpg** and then run the php file. This is the refined code. Let me know if this works for you.

```
<?php
$dir    = 'files/'; //directory
$files1 = scandir($dir);
shuffle($files1); //shuffle file names
$i           = 1; //initialize counter
//store existing numbered files in array
$exist_array = array();
while (in_array($i . ".jpg", $files1)) {
    array_push($exist_array, $i . ".jpg");
    $i++;
}
foreach ($files1 as $ff) {
    if ($ff != '.' && $ff != '..') // check for current or parent directory, else it will replace the directory name
        {
        // check whether the file is already numbered
        if (in_array($ff, $exist_array)) {
            continue;
        }
        //next 3 lines is proof of random rename
        echo $ff . "         --->     ";
        rename($dir . $ff, $dir . $i . ".jpg");
        echo $i . ".jpg<br/>";
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You must run the PHP file only once, else it will keep on replacing the renamed files randomly if executed again and again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it certainly renames the files but if I re run the script it deletes many files and even though the output says it has renamed one of the files to 1.jpg it doesn't actually do it.

Comment: see the output say 405.jpg ---> 1.jpg but 1.jpg doesnt exist and neither do any of the others, it looks like it is deleting instead of renaming
59.jpg ---> 2.jpg
429.jpg ---> 3.jpg
279.jpg ---> 4.jpg
395.jpg ---> 5.jpg

Comment: @John I have refined and updated the answer to fit your needs, Let me know. :)